# Your organization has reached its hourly limit for processing workflow time triggers

Tags: workflow, scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow, time

There are a lot of similar question, but I'm trying to research why I get this message.

I was looking into scheduled jobs and time based workflow. I am aware of the limits. Since I didn't find anything suspicious in the org, I'm thinking what if:

- there is a time based workflow that something is triggering way too much
- they have imported a lot of leads which triggered a lot of scheduled work

Questions that I have:

- can scheduled jobs from Apex give such issues or this is just the time based workflow thing?
- is there a way to see what was scheduled and processed a few days ago?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can scheduled jobs from Apex give such issues or this is just the time based workflow thing?

Apex Queueable, Batchable, Future methods, and Scheduled Jobs use the Asynchronous Apex limits, namely 250,000 executions per day. This limit is shared across all four types, and is enforced at execution time, not when the action Workflow Rule or Flow is initially triggered.

Workflow Rules and Flows that use Time-Dependent Actions are limited to 1,000 actions per hour. This limit is shared across both types.

> is there a way to see what was scheduled and processed a few days ago?

No, once executed, they are deleted and cannot be viewed. Also note that this is only a warning--the remaining items will be processed in the next hour. If you're constantly running into this, you may need to use an alternative solution, such as Scheduled Apex.

Unfortunately, forensics will likely be impossible, unless you have the paid [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring) feature.

Comment: Here is an idea on how to research it - look at the time-based workflows (Setup > Time-based workflows) to see if a single object (such as Lead) is loaded with them. If yes, then query the most recently updated Leads and check LastModifiedDate to see if a bunch of updates fired around when the error was received. Then check LastModifiedBy to see if they're all updated by a single user. If the user is a real person, ask them what they were up to.